# Sort a QuerySet by ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a model like this:

```
class my_model(models.Model)
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(My_other_model)
```

I want to get all Objects of `my_model` sorted by the number of objects in the foo field.
In [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254142/django-order-by-count-of-many-to-many-object) A friendly Guy from russia says, that you should use django-annontation.
I tried the following:

```
my_model.objects.all().order_by("-foo")
```

and it works fine. Is there any reason I should go the longer way with annotations??
Thx for help and stay healthy!

Comment: Have you tried this with mutliple test cases and confirmed that it actually sorts by the number of related objects? Seems weird to me...

Comment: Tried 2 times. It worked. But I also think its a little weird, so thats why I'm asking

Comment: Might be db-backend dependent. I'd go with sth. like `my_model.objects.annotate(c=Count('foo')).order_by('-c')` to be more explicit.

Comment: Danke Ich glaube so ist es wirklich am Besten! ;-)

Comment: Ha freilich! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet), your use case is okay to use just `.order_by()`. For more complex queries you will use the `.annotate()` like so:

```
below_5 = Count('book', filter=Q(book__rating__lte=5))
pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(below_5=below_5)
```

You can also make multiple annotations like so:

```
below_5 = Count('book', filter=Q(book__rating__lte=5))
above_5 = Count('book', filter=Q(book__rating__gte=5))
pubs = Publisher.objects.annotate(below_5=below_5).annotate(above_5=above_5)
```